# Random point inside a collection of Vector3 points

Tags: c#, xna, geometry

I have a program in XNA where the user can draw a circle (not a perfect circle - circling something freehand with the mouse). The resulting "circle" is stored as a list of Vector2 points (screen space). Converting those to 3d space is simple enough, but what I want to do after converting them is to treat the area encircled as a flat volume (everything at Z:0) and fill it with particles in a not entirely uniform manner. To accomplish this, I need to be able to assign particle positions to random points inside of the selected area. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find the bounding box of your points by going through your list of points, and detecting the `min` and `max` points along each axis (i.e. `minX`, `minY`, `maxX`, and `maxY`). Then generate yourself some random points within that bounding box by generating pairs of numbers `(x, y)` such that `minX < x < maxX` and `minY < y < maxY`, and check each random point to see if it is inside your user's "circle" (which is technically a *polygon*) by employing a [Point in Polygon algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon). If a point is inside the "circle", keep it; otherwise, generate a different random pair. This should give you `N` random points.

Comment: Using max./min. values as the first filtering does not deliver a reliable solution, unless for very specific, regular shapes (e.g., square or circle). For example the max. X value might only be applied on the min. Y and thus a point with this value at a higher height would be outside (but your algorithm wouldn't know it). That is, you are converting everything into a square what implies very important accuracy losses. I hope that you will not mind to discuss your approach to improve it under the current conditions (I was expecting a discussion in this question).

Comment: PS: even in case of taking a highly-simplified approach, it seems better here to rely on the closest-shape (a circle) and thus proposing something on the lines of the first two steps in my (deleted) answer: drawing a circle from the approx. middle point.

Comment: @varocarbas Drawing a circle may not give you a good enough approximation either: depending on the drawing skills of the human connecting the dots, the "circle" may look like anything at all. As far as the algorithm goes, it is not necessary to do the pre-filtering at all: the main point is using the point-in-polygon algorithm, which lets you detect if a point is inside very reliably, and throw away the points which are outside.

Comment: My comments referred to your starting "bounding box"; its definition is very inaccurate. If, afterwards, you want to check each single point, no error would logically appear but you might do that without the starting bounding box. It represents a first filtering? Yes, although a pretty "tolerant" one. My proposal of the circle was to create this bounding box (center + max/min) with a much closer shape  than what is expected. In any case I would go always for a more powerful first filtering like the two circles I proposed: internal circle, defined by the minimum distance to the centre, (...)

Comment: @varocarbas The probability of randomly hitting end-user's circle is higher when you generate the `(x,y)` pair inside the bounding box. The point of using it is to get your `N` points faster, that's all. The real work is done in the point-in-polygon.

Comment: ... and an external circle defined by the maximum distance (this external circle is equivalent to your bounding box, although closer to the real shape). All the points inside the internal circle would be assumed to be in; and you would have just to analyse the points outside it. Actually my proposal was more focused on the first filtering and yours in the final point-by-point calculations (I just proposed a simplistic: check the line drawn between the two closer contour points). (...)

Comment: (...) I hope that, after reading my last comment, you have understood that I am not suggesting performing random calculations from the start; right at the contrary: the importance of the first filtering (your bounding box) is very high and my concern was improving its accuracy and maximising its effect by delivering a better filtering. Well... this kind of conversation where you propose something and I improve some bits of your something (or you of mine) is the kind of output I was expecting from this question, rather than a "this is the solution, end of the story".